# Elasticsearch permissions system

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm searching for a search engine to use on an upcoming project and Elasticsearch so far seems a good fit I just have one requirement that I'm not sure how I can achieve it on Elasticsearch.

In my application I will have a set of forms and the user may me able to see it or not depending on their permissions. Every form as a unique set of custom permissions so how can I hide the forms that the user does not have access to from the search results?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create Role-based access. Define the roles for your users and use them as tags for the form data while storing it. Then your search query can use the role of the user to filter the tags in the data.

Hope this helps.